# Insert multiple row for the list of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to insert data to a table based on another table in SQL Management Studio 2014. I have a list of User having count `9500`. For each user I want to insert multiple data (Detailed data) in another table. Here is my Case:

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT, @Counter INT
DECLARE @TEMP1 TABLE (
    ROWID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    userName nvarchar(50),
    userEmail nvarchar(256)
)

insert into @TEMP1
select UserName, UserEmail from utblUsers

SET @COUNTER = 1
SELECT @MAXID = COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP1
declare @userEmail nvarChar(256),@UserName nvarchar(50)
WHILE (@COUNTER <= @MAXID/2)
BEGIN

    SELECT @userEmail=UserEmail, @UserName=UserName
    FROM @TEMP1 AS PT
    WHERE ROWID = @COUNTER
    exec sifms.dbo.sp_UserDetailInsert @UserName, @userEmail
    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END;
```

Here inside the loop I am calling `sp_UserDetailInsert` which is inserting data to my detail table which looks like this:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1,@sumAmount bigint, @deductedFromId int;
WHILE @cnt <= 5
BEGIN
    if @cnt=1  
    begin 
        -------Doing some calculation for SumAmount and get the deductedFromID
        Insert into utblUserDetails values (@UserName,@userEmail, @sumAmount, @deductedFromId)
    end
    else if @cnt=2  
    begin 
        -------Doing some calculation for SumAmount and get the deductedFromID
        Insert into utblUserDetails values (@UserName,@userEmail, @sumAmount, @deductedFromId)
    end
    .
    .
    .
    .
    else @cnt=5  
    begin 
        -------Doing some calculation for SumAmount and get the deductedFromID
        Insert into utblUserDetails values (@UserName,@userEmail, @sumAmount, @deductedFromId)
    end
END
```

My query is executing absolutely fine for few minutes. But the problems are

1. Query is executing very slowly
2. SQL Management Studio is getting closed after few minutes of execution.

I have tried clearing cache using

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL') 
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

But the result is still same. I have tried using cursor as well but cursor is much havier and it consume more memory than the loop. As the loop is light weight than cursor, I prefer loop in this case.I just want to get the user details at first and then I want to minimize the complexity.

Comment: A `CURSOR` will be an awful way to do this, that's why it's slow. To get a much better speed out of these, you'll need to use a dataset approach; unfortunately we don't have the full code so we're limited on what we can do here. As for why SSMS is closing; are you returning any datasets? I'd hazard a guess you are, and SSMS is running out of resources as it's only a 32bit application. *Also, note that SSMS and SQL Server aren't interchangeable words. SQL Server is your RDBMS, which is a Service, like IIS, and SSMS is an application, like Word, which is used to interact with SQL Server.*

Comment: Do go for insert multiple time. Create Multiple insert queries and then store them into a string variable and try to run that.

Comment: @Larnu the code is huge due to which I may not be able to provide here. Can you please explain the dataset approach?

Comment: @DeepakKumar if something went wrong in the insert query then it is more headache to debug.

Comment: @IswarKChettri you need to debug that and test that. This is one time job. That will more optimize solution. You can go for bulk insert. Instead of inserting one by one. But you have to choose and only you will have the better idea of your requirement. Cheers

Comment: Not really. Using a dataset approach is a way of thinking. I can't remember who I'm quoting here, however *"Don't think about what you want to do with a row, thing about what you want to do to a column."* is the mentality. The solution to changing a interactive process to a dataset process is different for almost every scenario, as each scenario is different. Perhaps a [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=HOw+to+change+a+cursor+to+a+dataset+approach+SQL+Sevrer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) will help.

Comment: Figure out how to insert all rows for *one* user record in a single `INSERT ... SELECT`. Then use `CROSS APPLY` on that `SELECT` to produce all records for all users in one go. You can use `WITH` to build up intermediate queries. As an intermediate measure, if the logic is too complicated to rewrite, you can stick it in a table-valued function to at least get the "all rows for one user" part in one statement. As for Management Studio, it runs out of memory quickly in grid view. Ensure your procedures aren't returning results when they shouldn't, or switch to "output to text".

Comment: @IswarKChettri are you trying to insert row by row data into user defined table

Comment: @KarunChettri Yes I am trying to insert data in user defined table for reportting purpose. Ultimately I want the `userDetails` in xml.

Comment: @IswarKChettri Have you tried using sqlcmd with administrative privileges

Comment: I am not sure about it. But can be helpful in my case as I am generating xml.

Comment: SQL Server has native support for producing XML using the `FOR XML` clause.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am able to get the xml when data is less. I guess the problem is because of 64 bit operating system the memory is out of bound

Comment: sample data and expected result would help us rewrite this